# php mail function from a adress with åäö?

Tags: php, email

Can you send a mail via php from a emailadress with ÅÄÖ?

Like this:

```
$to = "$email";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Test";
$from = "info@testwithÅÄÖ.se";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Comment: Have you tried to create an email address with special characters and sending a mail to it?

Comment: I didn't have a server so I asked first. Maybe there is someone that can answer my question. @Jerodev